# Is an emailExist method allowed in UserService?

Tags: php, pdo, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, ddd-service

I'm using domain driven design.

I've got the following model (classes):

- User
- UserDAO
- UserRepository
- UserService

I know that UserService is supposed to contain all the corresponding application logic. So I got methods like `signUp()`, `logIn()` and `update()` in there.

My `signUp()` method, signs a user up, but throws a PDO exception when the email UNIQUE constraint has been violated. Now, since exceptions are for **exceptional** errors only and bad for control flow my question is:

**Is an `emailExist()` method allowed to be in a UserService class?**

So I can call that first in my controller (so I can report back with a form error if the email already exist), before actually signing a user up. I know such method actually belongs in the data mapper, but since they aren't supposed to be used directly in controllers I thought about having it added to my UserService class and from there map it to my repository's `findByEmail()` method.

Comment: Not sure where you got the idea that exceptions are only for "exceptional error". Exceptions are excellent to report any deviation from the expected execution flow back to a caller without using out and ref parameters. You can specify granular exceptions for any fallback scenarios that you need and handle only those, re-throw anything else. And this "anything else" will be your "exceptional errors" flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Systems often expose commands and queries. SignUp, LogIn and Update are commands. FindByEmail is a query.

User interfaces are there to try and guide a user to composing a valid command. Checking if an email already exists in the UI can provide nicer feedback to the user - allowing him to correct the command before sending it.

Once you've done your best into guiding the user, you can just have your command throw an exception - without handling it in a clean way, because the chance that you get that far is now extremely small.

Comment: I'm sorry but, I'm a little bit confused by your answer to my question. Are you saying it's fine, or..?